# iOS 6 force an orientation

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

In iOS5 you could use this snippet to force the orientation:

```
UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[c release];
```

However this causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS6. How can a certain orientation be forced in iOS6?

Comment: under NDA - can't be answered.

Comment: Come on people, there's no need to pile on downvotes for any question about iOS 6. If something's still under NDA, just politely direct people to the developer forums. No need to get hostile.

Comment: I believe this answers the question better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone still cares about this, here's the iOS6 code snippet (I placed it in my viewDidLoad routine):

```
UIViewController *viewController    = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to complete the previous answer, you should do this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
    [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}];
```

And iOS 6 is no longer under NDA.

Comment: Is not my solution, I just updated it to the new obj-c style.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. In any case, don't forget to release the view controller.

Comment: Use ARC! And sorry if is dosen't work for you, this is just a ugly trick, sometimes work somes dosen't, at least for me in iOS 6 works half of the times, and actually if you build your App with xcode 4.4, seems to work most of the times (but doen't with xcode 4.5)

Answer (score 1):

At first `presentModalViewController` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` are deprecated and probably iOS6 will not use these methods correctly. You should use [similar methods with complition block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) instead.

The second thing is that `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` tries to dismiss self firstly. Is this correct in your case?

And last thing iOS6 is under NDA