# webview appears rotated in ios6 but it is appears ok <= ios 5.1 simulator

Tags: uiwebview, ios6, ios5.1

Hi there I have an app where I have set supported interface orientation is set as landscape (left home button), landscape(right home button)  in .plist file

and in the testviewcontroller.m file

I have the code: -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

what changes do I have to make for it to appear normal on ios6 simulator

Thanks

found an answer: -

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
{
    // how the view was configured before IOS6
    [self.window addSubview: navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
else
{
    // this is the code that will start the interface to rotate once again
    [self.window setRootViewController: self.navigationController];
}
```

from this link -

[IOS 6 force device orientation to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape)

but now with another problem in ios6 - clicking on a textbox doesn't invoke the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
{
    // how the view was configured before IOS6
    [self.window addSubview: navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
else
{
    // this is the code that will start the interface to rotate once again
    [self.window setRootViewController: self.navigationController];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

The UIKit section explains how to do rotations in iOS6.

Comment: I am not trying to rotate the device here. I am just loading the app in landscape mode in ios6.0 simulator and it appears rotated right but it apears alright in ios5.0

Comment: You want to handle orientation correctly right? You need to implement the iOS 6 rotation methods to do so. Details are in the release notes.