# iOS 6 Orientation with NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, orientation

I am currently developing an application that works with iOS 5 and iOS 6.
Most of my views are only on Portrait orientation except for 1.

**RotationNavigationController** : Main `UINavigationController` that overrides `supportedInterfaceOrientation` and `shouldAutorotate`.

**PageViewController** : Pushed in RotationNavigationController and is displayed in Portrait orientation only.

**ImageViewController** : Pushed after PageViewController. Is displayed with `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`.

Here's what I have in the `ImageViewController`'s `ViewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // currentMask is the value returned by supportedInterfaceOrientation
   [(RotationNavigationController*)self.navigationController setCurrentMask:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown];
   [(RotationNavigationController*)self.navigationController setShouldAutorotate:YES];
}
```

And when I `popViewController` from ImageViewController in landscape, I get back to PageViewController in landscape mode too whereas PageViewController only supports Portrait orientation.

Of course, I reset the mask in the ImageViewController's `viewWillDisappear` to Portrait.

Is there a way for PageViewController to remain in Portrait orientation ?

Comment: This has been discussed (and seems nontrivial) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link emrys57. I found out the solution down there, and it was quite trivial in the end :

In RotationNavigationController, just add the following method :

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```