# UITabBarController presentmodal AutoRotate Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have SubClass of `UITabBarController` for handle the rotation issue:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

And Now from one of the `UIViewController` in the `tabbatcontroller` i present a new `UIViewController`:

```
MainVC *mainVC = [[MainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mainNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

radioNav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:mainNav animated:YES];
```

And in this new Navigation i want to disable auto rotate and allow only portrait :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
```

But the rotation still working and when i rotate the screen the app go to landscape screen, how i can fix this issue?

Comment: You need to check every time current device Orientation or device status-bar Origination :- Please Check my answer on this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710899/force-portrait-in-one-view-controller-makes-other-to-be-in-portrait-initially/16711127#16711127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also subclass `UINavigationController` and put the following code in your subclass:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Then, init an instance of your subclass:

```
MainVC *mainVC = [[MainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainVC" bundle:nil];
MYSubclassedNavigationController *mainNav = [[MYSubclassedNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

radioNav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:mainNav animated:YES];
```