# Handling autorotation for one view controller in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, ios7

I've read many answers on SO but I can't seem to get autorotation working on iOS7.

I only need one view controller to rotate, so I don't want to set rotation settings in my Info.plist.

As I understand Apple's documentation, a single view controller can override global rotations settings (from Info.plist) by simply overriding two methods. Info.plist is set to only allow Portrait, and my view controller implements the following methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return true;
}
```

I'm seeing those NSLog statements upon rotation but nothing rotates.

If I do configure Info.plist with the proper rotation settings, my view will rotate, but not if I try and rely on my view controller.

Not sure if it matters, but the view I'm trying to rotate is from a .xib using auto layout.

Also, my ViewController is being presented modally and is contained in a navigation controller. I've tried just presenting the view controller by itself and that doesn't work. I've also tried [adding a category to UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004271/prevent-autorotate-for-one-view-controller#answer-15004471) to get it's autorotation directions from it's topViewController.

Comment: Same problem; in addition, I would like my app to be iOS5 compatible, so I can't use supportedInterfaceOrientations. I am using the other two functions: shouldAutorotate (returning NO) and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (although deprecated). They are not even called! It appears there is no way out!

Comment: I have finally given up... reviewed my xib so that the view appears in a somewhat reasonable way also in landscape orientation... :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the plist value to all possible values, then limit them as you see fit (in the Navigation Controllers and TabBar Controllers. From the UIViewController class description:

> In iOS 6 and later, your app supports the interface orientations
>   defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override
>   the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of
>   supported orientations. Typically, the system calls this method only
>   on the root view controller of the window or a view controller
>   presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the
>   portion of the window provided for them by their parent view
>   controller and no longer participate directly in decisions about what
>   rotations are supported. The intersection of the app’s orientation
>   mask and the view controller’s orientation mask is used to determine
>   which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.

Comment: So you put the shouldautorotate and supportedinterfaceorientations in the view controller before the one you want to rotate one specific way or what?

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I had a new iOS7 app with about 30 view controllers created already. I needed auto rotation on just a single modal view controller. I didn't want to have to update the preexisting view controllers.

I selected the orientations I wanted in the plist:

[image: select orientations]

Then I added a category to my app delegate on UIViewController:

```
@implementation UIViewController (rotate)
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
      return NO;
   }
@end
```

Then in the single modal view controller I WANTED to rotate I added this method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
      return YES;
}
```

I also discovered, that if my view controller wasn't a modal VC I would need to add category methods on UINavigationController instead, for all VCs that were subsequent to the root view controller, as part of the navigation stack of view controllers - similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283331/396429

Comment: You should not use categories to override methods. The clean way of doing the exact same thing is creating a base class for all your UIViewControllers and override the method there.

Comment: The whole point of my answer is to show how the objective is achievable without subclassing UIViewController. In some cases it isn't practical to do so

Comment: @Nate, the whole point of your answer is incorrect, category cannot be used for this since your case is a particular one, when it works. When you override a method using a category there is no guarantee that it will actually override it, it can still pick the old one.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c for more details

Answer (score 16):

Simple but it work very fine. IOS 7.1 and 8

AppDelegate.h

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if(self.restrictRotation)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

ViewController

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

viewDidLoad

```
[self restrictRotation:YES]; or NO
```

Comment: That is the clever solution i find around there. 
i may add that if in the same stack, one view controller is not restricted, the rest of the view controller should have [self restrictRotation:YES]; in the viewWillAppear (for when you push back button.) 
thank you Alan ! you're the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced such problem - had only one landscape view in my app.
I've used below code to to handle that.

```
#import "objc/message.h"
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: Love it! hack and slash

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I ended up in a more unique situation where we have 50+ ViewController all over the app that I refused to go through and modify and support the same orientation in all of them but one or 2. Which brings me to my answer. I created a UIViewController category that overrides - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate to always return NO or YES depending on device type etc. (this can be done with supported interface orientations too). Then on the ViewControllers I wanted to support more then just portrait, I swizzled shouldAutorotate to return YES. Then forced the orientation change when the view is dismissed on the parent ViewControllers viewWillAppear method using:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"].`

When all was said and done, I accomplished everything I wanted on a few ViewControllers with < 30 lines of code using a macro for swizzling. Had I done it by replacing shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations on all of the VC's in the application I would have ~250 extra lines of code. and a lot of grunt work adding it in the first place.