# iOS: AVPlayerViewController enable fullscreen rotation in portrait oriented application

Tags: ios, avfoundation, fullscreen, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a UIViewcontroller, which contains a AVPlayerViewController with AVPlayer.
I want to enable rotation for AVPlayerViewController(when video is on fullscreen) and disable any rotation for UIViewController.
How can I enable rotation only for videos(on fullscreen) in my app?

Comment: Have you implemented `supportedInterfaceOrientations` appropriately?

Comment: @matt I just return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait in supportedInterfaceOrientations method. UIViewController does not rotate and AVPlayer to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Swift 2.2**
In AppDelegate to allow rotation for player:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        guard let vc = (window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController) else {
            return .Portrait
        }

        if (vc.isKindOfClass(NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController")!)) {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        }

        return .Portrait
    }
```

Than create and use subclass of AVPlayerViewController for back to portrait mode when player exit full screen mode:

```
class YourVideoPlayer: AVPlayerViewController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if view.bounds == contentOverlayView?.bounds {
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome ! Where did you find the informations about avplayer?

Comment: >= iOS 10, AVPlayerViewController handles landscape support for video playback in portrait-only apps, thus you should avoid using this hack.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was better. Just extend **AVPlayerViewController** :

```
import AVKit
import UIKit

class AVPlayerViewControllerRotatable: AVPlayerViewController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Swift 4

Comment: way much easier than dealing with rotation orientation in app delegate level!

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that it says, "The framework doesn’t support subclassing AVPlayerViewController." in the Apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: Wouv it has been more than 5 years :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the allowable rotations at the project level and then restrict rotation on all the viewControllers you DON'T want to rotate.  i.e. if you have 5 viewControllers, you'll need to restrict rotation on 4 of them and only allow rotation on the Player Controller.  You can see more on this here [Handling autorotation for one view controller in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502251/handling-autorotation-for-one-view-controller-in-ios7)