# How to force set Landscape Orientation with UINavigationController (Swift 2.0 iOS 9)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I tried to find a solution but so much information which doesn't work. My last try was using the following:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight, animated: false)
```

This however, was deprecated from iOS 9 and couldn't find any way to force rotate with `UINavigationController`. My app mainly uses Portrait Orientation and only one view needs to be Landscape. I need to force Landscape on one View and rest to keep as Portrait. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Some of the questions I checked are:

[Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

[How do I programmatically set device orientation in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987249/how-do-i-programmatically-set-device-orientation-in-ios7)

[Why can't I force landscape orientation when use UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658268/why-cant-i-force-landscape-orientation-when-use-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is something you really want to do, subclass `UINavigationController` then add this code:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape
}
```

Trying to force an orientation imperatively is unwise; it's better to tell iOS what you want (as above) then let it calculate the orientation as best it can.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! Unfortunately, this still doesn't work.. :/

Comment: How do you force an orientation change when pushing/popping view controllers with different orientations (e.g., A -> portrait, B -> landscape)? So popping from B->A should yield portrait while pushing A->B should yield landscape.

Answer (score 0):

We had to do this same thing in our app as well. Initially we worked with a hack. But eventually we switched the "Landscape" VC to a modal rather than part of navigation view controller stack. I would suggest you do that. But if you really want to, here is how you do it.

Subclass Navigation VC. 
in `supportedInterfaceOrientaions` check for VC type & return appropriate orientation (landscape for one you want, portrait for rest)
This itself wont autorotate that VC to landscape, so here is the hack.

In `viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear` of "landscape" VC, push another generic VC object & pop it subsequently

```
UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

This used to work in iOS7 & we switched to modal after that. so this might now work in later versions.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but got an error - DeviceOrientation[4624:222192] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <DeviceOrientation.LandscapeViewController: 

I think I will try you first option. How would you recommend making it modal rather than part of a nav controller? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this was an issue that came up with our app too, but it was just a warning. For presenting VC as a modal you need to change the segue kind to **modal** & then `performSegueWithIdentifier` . You will need to take care of adding navigationbar yourself as this modal VC wont be a part of navigationVC stack. 

All other usual VC apis should return appropriate values

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` should return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`


`shouldAutorotate` should return `YES` 

There wont be a back button, so you should add that too in top bar.