# Two views for a single view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am totally new to iOS programming. I am developing an app where I need a different view for portrait and another for landscape orientation. Even if the view is different, the buttons and other controls are the same in both the views. So I want to keep the same connections from the buttons/labels to the view controller for both the views. so that if I change the value of a label in my view controller, it should change in the view irrespective of the view I am presenting.

Now the problem I am facing is that I am not able to add two different root views to an item in the story board. I have tried to add two different sub views to the main view. That way I am able to create the views, but I am not able to connect buttons from both the views to a single connection. For example,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonNext;
```

can be connected to a next button in only one view.

Inorder to get around that problem, I have created two different views in the story board, added the same view controller for both. Then created a segue for each view as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;
```

And in my view controller I have added:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
[self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
//NSLog(self.view.restorationIdentifier);
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    if(self.landscapeView == nil)
    {
        self.landscapeView =[[UIView alloc] init];
    }
   self.view = landscapeView;
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    self.view = portraitView;
}
}
```

The problem is that the second view is not loading properly. Initially it is getting loaded as nil. Even when I initialize the view in the code, it is not initializing subviews/controls inside the view. I am stuck with this for the past three days. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

I have added a sample code in here: http://cl.ly/2z3f3E290f0R

Answer (score 3):

U can try this with single view :

**First**

In `viewDidLoad` method, code for **Device Orientation**

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

**Second**

Method for **OrientationChanged**

```
-(void)orientationChanged {

    //Check for Portrait Mode
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
       x=25; y=30;
    }
    //Lanscape mode
    else {
       x=50; y=40;
    }

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
}
```

Here, you can take 'X' & 'Y' whatever you want.

This method always calls whenever device will be rotated.

Hopefully, it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am looking at using two different views rather than resizing/re positioning the objects. Otherwise it will be very tedious for me to make this change in every screen because it is a rich UI.

Comment: But, as you said earlier that you have to use same object(i.e. button), then how will you manage with multiple connection for same object. Then you need to resize controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UIDeviceOrientation newOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if (newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown && newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp && newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown)
        {
            if(orientation != newOrientation)
            {
                //ORIENTATION HAS CHANGED. Do orientation logic
                if(
                   (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)&&(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
                {
                    NSLog(@"Changed orientation to Landscape");
                    // Clear the current view and insert the orientation-specific view
                    [self clearCurrentView];
                    [self.view insertSubview:titleLandscapeView atIndex:0];
                }
                else if (
                         (newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)&&(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
                {
                    NSLog(@"Changed orientation to Portrait");
                    // Clear the current view and insert the orientation-specific view
                    [self clearCurrentView];
                    [self.view insertSubview:titlePortraitView atIndex:0];
                }
                orientation = newOrientation;
            }

 -(void) clearCurrentView{
        if (titleLandscapeView.superview){
            NSLog(@"clear titleLandscapeView");
            [titleLandscapeView removeFromSuperview];
        } else if (titlePortraitView.superview){
            NSLog(@"clear titlePortraitView");
            [titlePortraitView removeFromSuperview];
        } else
        {
            NSLog(@"Neither titleLandscapeView nor titlePortraitView");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still having the same issue. It is loading the an empty portrait view

Comment: have u given iboulets the views and when are u adding the subview i mean in which method

Comment: Also u need to add two views inside your self.view.

Comment: I have modified the question and added a link to a sample solution with the problem. Could you please have a look?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape