# How to fix a specific orientation to a viewcontroller in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

I am working on an iPad app. It is to capture the image in popover and crop the image in full screen in next view. Here it consists of following screens

1) `LoginViewContoller`(need all orientations),

2)`SplitViewController`(need all orientations),`

3)`ImageCropViewController`(need only landscape),

4)`SettingsViewController`(need all orientations).

In `ImageCropViewController` I am writing following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I am getting the exact orientation. But Its effecting `LoginViewController's` and `SettingViewController's` Orientation also.

In `LoginViewController` and `SettingViewController` ,i am writing following code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES;
    }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

While navigating from `SplitViewController` to `ImageCropViewController` ,i am initiating the `ImageCropViewController` as `rootViewController`.

In plist I have supported orientations like this

[image]
 I googled it. And integrated the available codes. But I did not find any solution. Please help me. Its really killing my time.

Comment: This is on iOS 6, correct?

Comment: So all these views are inside a UINavigationController?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have it set up on my iPhone Project but it shouldn't be any different for yours:

First, make sure your Project supports all of your desired orientations:

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]

Then, override these methods on your SplitViewController, ImageCropViewController and SettingsViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Finally, override these methods on your ImageCropViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Perhaps it's the shouldAutorotate methods the ones your are missing.

Comment: I have done same as u said.But facing the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question @pedro.m

Comment: Your question shows you are returning NO in one of your shouldAutorotate methods. Change it to YES.

Comment: Also, are you using any form of custom UIViewController containment?

Comment: Try overriding this method, see if it is getting called at some point:

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

Comment: nope I am not using any custom ViewControler

Comment: ok>.I will let you know