# UIInterfaceOrientation landscape Vs Portrait issue in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I think I have gone over almost every single post on this topic. So don't kill the question yet till you read. This question is for XCode 5 on iOS 7

I have an app that supports both landscape and portrait modes. In my projects Deployment info all orientations are checked.

When app launches I show

- v1ViewController (which always should open in landscape mode)

When a user hits a button it takes them to

- v3ViewController (which always should open in portrait mode)

The problem I have is that when app launches and I am holding the iphone in portrait mode it show this.

[image]

If I swtich the iphone in landscape mode it shows this.

[image]

How can I force my v1ViewController to always show landscape mode?

This is the code I have right now.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

But if I add this then the view always opens like the first picture I show and rotation has no effect.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    NSLog(@"interfaceOrientation: %d ...", interfaceOrientation);



    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 }

 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
 }
```

Comment: may be this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape/13360116#13360116

    if you still face the problem then let me know

Comment: @AnuragSoni thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: so your problem is solved or not?

Comment: yes, its resolved. I had posted an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone interested in how I got it working, this is what I did.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```